# Reading csv file as data frame in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and I have a csv file with over 1500 columns. I like to load it as a dataframe in spark. I am not sure how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this project https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

There is an example from the front page:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("cars.csv")
```